# Непонятный скролинг Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, wordpress

На [сайте](http://www.remob.lv/) возникла непонятная ошибка - на webkit браузерах при загрузке страницу прокручевает вниз. Причем скрипта по прокрутке нет. Может, посмотрите, подскажите, где ошибка может возникать. Появилась после добавления это проверил пудем отключение всех скриптов (через девелопер) скрипты не работают а скролинг  вниз работает то есть это наверное вообще не скрипты. Как можно отследить все действия браузера при его загрузке ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри, у тебя написано:

```
var input = $('#form_search_tel input').focus;
```

Попробуй вбей то же самое в консоли - получишь undefined.

А вот если в консоли введешь так:

```
var input = $('#form_search_tel input').focus(); //добавил скобки
```

то тебе отфокусит к форме и проскроллит вниз. :)
Непонятно, что ты хочешь этим добиться:

```
var input = $('#form_search_tel input').focus;
```

Comment: ну мне надо что бы происходил клик проходил только если поле инпут выбрано (можно поменять на заполненое)ю Но я удаляю код вот сейчас к примеру без этого кода и ни чего. Вообще ни чего. Тоесть ошибка не в этом коде.

Comment: Если тебе надо событие на фокус, то юзай так:
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Да причем здесь событие на фокус, я стер весь код вообще. Считайте, нет кода. Вы что, не можете посмотреть по ссылке? 
Я не могу понять, в чем ошибка, причем только у web-kit браузеров, мозила и ie - все в порядке. А вы мне все про фокус.